# The output from the .fit_transform method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'd like to have a deeper understanding of what is being output by the method .fit_transform() in the PolynomialFeatures class in scikit learn.

I understand that the method is doing two things, 1) generating a model to the data by fitting it to a regression algorithm, and 2) creating new data based on the model found in 1.

But what I am not understanding is the output. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
X_train1 = X_train.reshape(11,1)
y_train1 = y_train.reshape(11,1)

def answer_one():
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

    poly1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)

    X_poly1 = poly1.fit_transform(X_train1)

    return X_poly1

answer_one()
```

The output I get is:

```
array([[  1.        ,  10.08877265],
       [  1.        ,   3.23065446],
       [  1.        ,   1.62431903],
       [  1.        ,   9.31004929],
       [  1.        ,   7.17166586],
       [  1.        ,   4.96972856],
       [  1.        ,   8.14799756],
       [  1.        ,   2.59103578],
       [  1.        ,   0.35281047],
       [  1.        ,   3.375973  ],
       [  1.        ,   8.72363612]])
```

I assume each second number in each mini array is a value calculated by the model, but I don't understand what each 1 is?

Comment: What you have there is the solution to your linear equation system y = a + bx in matrix form y = [1, x(i)]*[a, b]. a is just your y-intercept and b is your slope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`PolynomialFeatures`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) documentation:

> Generate a new feature matrix consisting of all polynomial
>   combinations of the features with degree less than or equal to the
>   specified degree. For example, if an input sample is two dimensional
>   and of the form [a, b], the degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b,
>   a^2, ab, b^2].

In your case the output is all the combinations of column `x` with degree less than or equal to 1: `[1, x]`. In the first column you have `x**0` and in the second `x**1`

Comment: I thought I got it, but now I am not sure I do.  I now understand that its giving me the 1 because it's a x**0, and 0 is power less than my chosen polynomial degree, but why 11 mini-arrays?

Comment: is it correct to say that each mini-array represents all the features (here, 2) used to create one point, and its 11 because the input had 11 points?

Answer (score 2):

You've slightly misunderstood what's going on with `PolynomialFeatures`. The idea is not to fit a model at all, but simply create new features by multiplying together existing features. The example in the docs is quite helpful to explain, if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form `[a, b]`, the degree-2 polynomial features are `[1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2]`.

So what you're seeing in your example is just the bias along with your input. If set `include_bias=False' in your model then the ones will go.